# #ifdef query and clarification needed

Tags: c

I see constructions like:

```
#ifdef FOO || defined BAR
...
#endif
```

and compiler's complaints "warning: extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive", obviously it should be:

```
#if defined FOO || defined BAR
...
#endif
```

Does the standard explicitly say so? Could you point at the relevant part?

Comment: I always thought `#ifdef` only worked for single symbols. I read it as, `if the symbol, <token> is defined...`.

Answer (score 5):

In C99, *6.10 Preprocessing directives*, paragraph 1 is Syntax:

```
if-group:
# if constant-expression new-line groupopt
# ifdef identifier new-line groupopt
# ifndef identifier new-line groupopt
```

It shows your first construction with `#ifdef` is incorrect as only an identifier can follow the `#ifdef`,  a constant expression is not allowed.